# If you can embedd php into a .html file, why would you use .php?

Tags: php, html, organization, embedding

Is there a reason why certain pages are made as .php when you can put php into a .html file? Is it simply for the sake of organizing your files? Or does it affect how the page loads?

(I'm talking about the file extension)

Comment: The question is perfectly fine and justified.  +1 to even out the downvote.

Comment: nope. server side newbie here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether files with the extension `.html` are parsed as PHP is down to the server's configuration. Usually, they're not.

That is for a reason: When set that way, the PHP interpreter has to look over *every* HTML file that gets served, even if it doesn't contain any PHP code at all. That's not good for performance.

Comment: @tom I have one of my webservers set to send `.scary` to the php processor too. You can set it up how you want, the defaults exist for the reasons pekka said though.

Answer (score 6):

File extensions are merely a convention. You can save a JPEG picture with `.html` extension and configure things to get it properly loaded. And, of course, being a convention, there's nothing magical in them: renaming `foo.mpg` to `foo.avi` won't convert your movie to DivX. The Unix operating system doesn't even use extensions to identify programs.

But, of course, they're a *very useful* convention. If your text editor opens a `.php` file, it doesn't need to guess what syntax highlighter to apply. If the web server serves a `.php` files, you don't have to instruct it to handle it to the PHP interpreter.

Some more remarks:

- There're many server-side languages; PHP is not the only one.
- The PHP interpreter does not care about the file extension.
- URLs reflect the file they load almost as many times as they don't.
- PHP can generate HTML... and GIF pictures, an PDF documents, and MP3 recordings...

Comment: Stack Overflow should warn you when the user has accepted an answer on the question you're typing. It feels like a waste of time.

Comment: It's still a fine answer with advanced points and background.